# Please help me with this oop code on php.net site

Tags: php, oop

I didn't get why the first output of the code prints "Bar::testPrivate" as we are   calling the test method of the parent class using sub class's instance.So, when calling the first line of code inside the test function which is "$this->testPrivate();" should call testPrivate method of the sub class hence printing "Foo::testPrivate" and not "Bar::testPrivate".

```
<pre>
class Bar 
{
    public function test() {
        $this->testPrivate();
        $this->testPublic();
    }

    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Bar::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Bar::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar 
{
    public function testPublic() {
        echo "Foo::testPublic\n";
    }

    private function testPrivate() {
        echo "Foo::testPrivate\n";
    }
}

$myFoo = new foo();
$myFoo->test(); // Bar::testPrivate 
                // Foo::testPublic



</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class `Foo` doesn't have a `test()` method. You can call `$myFoo->test()` because the method `test()` is inherited from class `Bar`. You'll have to override the method `test()` within class `Foo` just as you did with methods `testPrivate()` and `testPublic()`.

You are correct that it is calling the method of the base class, but in this case `Bar` is your base class. Check out the example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php).

Comment: Let's go with the flow...say $myFoo->test(); will call the test method of the parent class.Now inside the test method the first statement being $this->testPrivate()...$this in this context should refer to $myFoo...so we can view the call $this->testPrivate() as $myFoo->testPrivate()...which should call the testPrivate() method of the Foo class...Plz tell me where i am going wrong...

Comment: I'm not exactly positive how it get's back to that part of the code, whether it be through the stack or whatnot, but either way, your code is in the "Bar" class. So any reference to `$this` is a reference to whatever class it's actually written in... P.S. Thanks Paulo, for the edit.

Comment: @seemywingz.."So any reference to $this is a reference to whatever class it's actually written in"....If that is true then calling $this->testPublic(); via $myFoo->test(); should result in Bar::testPublic and not  Foo::testPublic...But that's not the case here...I m really not able to get it...Plz explain..

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to inherit all the functions from your base (parent) class then you should explicitly call it's constructor in the child class.  Otherwise you will need to override those methods.  Also, when using the actual instance (i.e. you created an object)  functions declared `private` are only available to that class. Use `protected` for classes that will inherit that function. e.g.:

```
class Foo {

    public function __construct() {
        echo "Foo constructed...\n";
        $this->fooOnly();
    }

    private function fooOnly() {
        echo "Called 'fooOnly()'\n";  //Only available to class Foo
    }

    protected function useThisFoo() {
        echo "Called 'useThisFoo()'\n";  //Available to Foo and anything that extends it.
    }

}

class Bar extends Foo {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();  //Now Bar has everything from Foo
    }

    public function testFooBar() {
        //$this->fooOnly(); //Fail - private function
        $this->useThisFoo(); //Will work - protected function is available to Foo and Bar
    }

}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->testFooBar();  //Works - public function will internally call protected function.
//$bar->fooOnly();  //Fail - private function can't be accessed in global space
//$bar->useThisFoo();  //Fail again - protected function can't be access in global space
```